# Getting time from scapy packet

Tags: python, scapy

I just want to get timestamp from packet that was stored in database like raw bytes.

```
>>> type(packet)
<class 'scapy.layers.inet.IP'>
>>> packet.time
1447958279.494598
>>> packet_string = str(packet)
>>> packet_string
'E\x00\x00<\xd6#@\x00@\x06f\x96\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x7f\x00\x00\x01
\xc8\xb509\xe0\xc7!!\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x02\xaa\xaa\xb3T\x00
\x00\x02\x04\xff\xd7\x04\x02\x08\n\x00\x00\xf7\x02\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x01\x03\x03\x07'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> packet_from_string = IP(packet_string)
>>> packet_from_string
<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=60 id=54819 flags=DF frag=0L 
ttl=64 proto=tcp chksum=0x6696 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 
options=[] |<TCP  sport=51381 dport=12345 seq=3771146529 ack=0 
dataofs=10L reserved=0L flags=S window=43690 chksum=0xb354 urgptr=0 
options=[('MSS', 65495), ('SAckOK', ''), ('Timestamp', (63234, 0)), 
('NOP', None), ('WScale', 7)] |>>
>>> packet.time
1447958279.494598
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(packet.time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2015-11-20 00:37:59'
>>> packet_from_string.time
1447960493.24821
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(packet_from_string.time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2015-11-20 01:14:53'
```

How can I get the real timestamp from packet that was builded from raw bytes?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Which timestamp do you need and from what kind of packets? And in what format of raw bytes? E.g. if you read in pcap file using rdpcap then pkt.time field will represent timestamp as read from pcap file (which is stored there as two integers - seconds and miliseconds, and converted to float while reading). This is not available as raw bytes. Or you want timestamp from TCP layer?